# Heroku push fog error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fog

When i push my app to heroku server below error was occur and did not start thin server, it works early master push, But unfortunately it has stopped pushing. Blow i added the error log,

But in localhost it is working and start thin server , Is that heroku error?.

Here is my Procfile info

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

The heroku error log

```
Could not detect rake tasks
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no  environment variables present
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
This may be intentional, if you expected rake tasks to be run
cancel the build (CTRL+C) and fix the error then commit the fix:
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Fog::Service 

/tmp/build_4daef779061b871c10200675ed5cb467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fog-  aws-0.1.2/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb:3:in `<module:Storage>'
```

Comment: I help maintain Fog on behalf of Rackspace. Do you have fog listed in your gemfile? In the production group?

Comment: Yes here is my gem 
gem 'fog', '~> 1.29.0', require: "fog/aws/storage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We made a small change to simplify requires which accidentally introduced this issue. I think if you remove the `require: "fog/aws/storage"` part of the gemfile, such that it just uses fog normally, that it should work for you. See also: https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/issues/83

Comment: Thank you for replay this was worked, But in had issue with this "gem 'asset_sync'", So i decide to go for gem 'carrierwave-aws' this working fine but need to change confitarion file.

Comment: You just use `gem 'fog-aws'` instead.